# Transformar maiúscula em minúscula em string

Tags: c, string

Preciso fazer uma função que receba duas strings, e troque ambas de lugares. Mas se tiver uma letra maiúscula na primeira, na hora de converter precisa ir para minúscula. Eu tentei fazer, só que acho que está errado dentro do meu `while`. O que posso fazer?

Nota: não posso usar funções da 'string.h'.

```
void str_troca(char origem[], char minusc[])
{   
 char aux[MAX];
    int i=0;  
    int a=1;  
    int b=0;  

    while(origem[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(origem[i]>64 && origem[i]<91)
        {
            origem[i]-32;
        }
        i++;
    }


    aux[i]=origem[i];
    origem[i]=minusc[i];
    minusc[i]=aux[i];

    printf("%s\n",minusc );
    printf("%s\n",origem );  

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você quase acertou, só cometeu um pequeno erro bobo. No lugar disso:

```
        origem[i]-32;
```

Use isso:

```
        origem[i]+=32;
```

Ou seja, era para usar mais ao invés de menos e faltou o sinal de igual.

Dito isso, pode-se fazer mais algumas sugestões. Para que o código seja legível, substitua `>64` por `>= 'A'` e substitua `<91` por `<= 'Z'`. Assim, fica bem claro que você está olhando para letras maiúsculas e não precisa ficar decorando ou consultando a tabela ASCII com números arbitrários e arcanos. Da mesma forma, você pode usar `origem[i] += 'a' - 'A';` - isso pode, de uma certa forma, ser lido como "coloque (+) a minúscula e tire (-) a maiúscula".

Comment: nossa, erro besta kkkk. Vlw mano, ajudou mto kkk

Comment: Boa a sua dica do  `>='A'` mas tem que tomar cuidado para colocar aspas simples e não aspa dupla.